# Is it possible to define special folder for shared views in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Currently the root of my Pages folder I have 5 files:

- `_ViewStart.cshtml`
- `_ViewImport.cshtml`
- `_Layout.cshtml`
- `_LayoutInner.cshtml`
- `Index.cshtml` - finally I page I actually use

That looks a little bit messy, especially with potential of having more `_Layout` files. So, is it possible to move "special" files (with underscore prefix) to "special" folder, like it was case in ASP.NET MVC with Shared?

Or I am required to keep carrying these files in root of my Razor views folder?

Answer (score 1):

`ViewStart` and `ViewImport` have special meanings in hierarchical folder structures, so they definitely need to stay in root. They can be overridden with files having the same name in subfolders.

As for Layout files, they don't need to be there so I moved them to `Shared` subfolder and updated the `Layout` property in `ViewStart`.